# According to Catholicism, can "co-parents-in-law" marry?

Tags: catholicism, marriage, canon-law

Same question as [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41600/can-co-parents-in-law-marry-for-example-a-husbands-father-and-a-wifes-mother) but for Catholicism. I don't see how a married couple's becoming step-siblings is any different from step-siblings' become a married couple.

Suppose Alice and Bob are widows (or single adoptive parents or unmarried biological parents or whatever) and their respective children are Charlie and Dalia. Suppose all 4 are not married (or were never married or whatever, depends if widow or not) and none of them have ever divorced or annulled.

If Alice and Bob marry, then [I think](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91992/can-step-siblings-marry-in-catholicism) Charlie and Dalia cannot marry. But if Charlie and Dalia marry, then can Alice and Bob marry afterwards?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but [Cdl. Cajetan, O.P., discussed the validity of levirate marriages like Henry VIII's with Catherine of Aragon](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9149). (Levirate marriages are when a brother marries his widowed sister-in-law.)

Answer (score 2):

**Q: Can co-parents-in-law marry?**

**A: Alice and Bob would be able to enter a valid marriage.**

[This commentary](https://canonlawmadeeasy.com/2010/09/09/can-cousins-marry-in-the-church/) of Canon Law gives some background.

> [Marriage] is invalid between persons related by *consanguinity* **in all degrees of the direct line** (c. 1091.1), and that in the *collateral line*, marriage is invalid **up to and including the fourth degree** (c. 1091.2).

“**Consanguinity**” refers only to biological, blood relationships (and not to relationships created through marriage, such as that between a mother-in-law and her son-in-law)."

"The “**direct line**” refers to direct descendants—parents, grandparents, children and grandchildren."

"The term “**collateral line**” refers to all relationships that at least partly involve siblings. Brothers and sisters are the clearest example of relatives in the collateral line, but collateral-line consanguinity refers also to relations between aunt/uncle and niece/nephew—as well as to cousins."

Now, in this question there is no mention whatsoever of consanguinity. The question here is of *affinity*. The same website has [this article](https://canonlawmadeeasy.com/2013/12/05/can-catholics-marry-in-laws/) addressing your exact question.

> A relationship of **affinity** arises from a valid marriage, and it pertains to the wife and the blood relatives of her husband, or the husband and the blood relatives of his wife.

> Affinity is calculated just like consanguinity is, in lines and degrees (cf. c. 109.2).  The relationship between a mother-in-law and her son-in-law, or a daughter-in-law and her father-in-law, is said to be in the direct line; while brothers- and sisters-in-law (as well as nieces/nephews, cousins, and even more distant relatives) are related in the collateral line.
>
> Note that the code is completely silent about affinity in the collateral line—which means that there is no prohibition at all. It is thus possible to marry a brother- or sister-in-law, or the cousin of one’s deceased spouse.

But your question is not of someone marrying *their* inlaw. But of someone marrying the in-law of a son or daughter.

Affinity "**pertains to the wife and the blood relatives of her husband, or the husband and the blood relatives of his wife.**"

Meaning that Alice and Bob *have no affinity*! If Charlie and Dalia were married, the only affinity change would be Charlie with Dalia's family, and Dalia with Charlie's family. The wikipedia article on [affinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_(Catholic_canon_law)) mentions this principle: "affinity does not beget affinity".

Comment: Thanks. Re 'But your question is not of someone marrying *their* inlaw. But of someone marrying the in-law of a son or daughter.' --> 1 - So it's that a co-(parent-in-law) is somehow not viewed necessarily as a '(co-parent)-in-law' I guess? 2 - So, really, step-siblings cannot marry, but a married couple can become step-siblings? The affinity thing makes sense for twin brothers and twin sisters to marry but come on widows and their children?!

Comment: 3 - If Alice-Bob wedding happens within 2 seconds from Charlie-Dalia wedding (oh say they're not so close with their parents/children to the point they don't even tell them about their new relationship), then it's possible 1 marriage may be void **depending on which happens 1st**? See? It doesn't matter if in twin boys and twin girls the older twins marry 1st or the younger twins marry 1st (assuming the only possible relationships are matching birth orders). But when it comes to widows and their children................the order matters?

Comment: 4 - Please link/quote/cite specifically something about co-parents-in-law. All this terminology (consanguinity, direct, collateral, affinity, blahx3) seems like it'd take time to understand. So far what I'm reading seems like maybe it would imply co-parents-in-law may marry, but I'm not seeing anything explicit AND specific about the co-parents-in-law thing.

Comment: Re: 4 I have links and definitions for each of those terms... I'm not sure what else you are asking for; more detail and links are also in the articles I linked. "Co-parents-in-law" is not a defined term in Canon Law. Canon Law is descended from old Roman law, as such it defines familial relations in terms of direct/collateral line, and in terms of degrees of consanguinity/affinity.

Comment: On 3 I'm not really sure what all you're asking. C-D marriage does not affect A-B marriage at all, whether it happens before, after, or not at all. The marriage of step-siblings is a separate question that I'll look for, but should be answered well enough by the website I linked

Comment: 1. Like I said earlier, "co-parent-in-law" is just not a relationship that exists within canon law. A man shares no affinity whatsoever with the blood relations of the spouse of his own blood relation. This is what "Affinity does not beget affinity" means.

Comment: Step-siblings don't share any degree of consanguinity (no blood relation) or affinity (only with the spouse of their bio parent) and so it seems to me that step-siblings *could* contract a valid marriage.

Comment: Thanks. Hmmmm....in the catholic church can step-siblings marry? Actually this is my 1 big assumption that's apparently false outside catholicism or religion or whatever.

Comment: Full post: [Can step-siblings marry in Catholicism?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91992/can-step-siblings-marry-in-catholicism)

Comment: Actually about this https://christianity.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/76430 i think we're both wrong. it should be a case of 'not necessarily' again as in the other question: 'Alice and Bob would not necessarily be hindered from entering a valid marriage if Charlie and Dalia have married.'

Comment: Thanks. Ok I guess I don't think you're wrong or anything, but what I'm not really seeing is something really explicit. It says 'It is thus possible to marry a brother- or sister-in-law, or the cousin of one’s deceased spouse.' ok that's good. What I'm hoping for is something explicit like cathy Caridi would say 'an unmarried male can marry his son/daughter's wife's/husband's unmarried mother' or at least 'the code is completely silent about whether or not (insert preceding quote)'. Anything?

Comment: "_Alice and Bob have no affinity_", assuming they're not married to each other.

Comment: @Geremia Is there any harm in saying 'do not necessarily have affinity' instead of 'do not have affinity' ?

Comment: @BCLC What do you mean?